# Nested SQL query using three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, nested

I got three tables:

**Article_Size_Class**

- Article_ID
- Size_Class

**Sizes_not_availabe**

- Size_Class
- Size_ID

**Size_Table**

- Size_ID
- Length

So I got an **Article_ID** and now I want to list all the available product lengths from my **Size_Table** expect the ones listed in the **Sizes_not_availabe** table.

I tried to do this, but unfortunately it is not working:

```
SELECT *
FROM Size_Table
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT Size_ID
FROM Sizes_not_availabe
LEFT JOIN Article_Size_Class
ON Article_Size_Class.Size_ID = Article_Size_Class.Size_ID
WHERE Article_Size_Class.Article_ID= '00024-002'
)
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: `ON Article_Size_Class.Size_ID = Article_Size_Class.Size_ID` The `ON` clause should compare between the two tables, not the same table.

Comment: You also need some reference to `Size_Table` in the subquery. Otherwise it will show all or none of the rows in `Size_Table` depending on whether the subquery finds anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT st.Length FROM Size_Table st
WHERE
st.Size_ID NOT IN
(SELECT sna.Size_ID FROM Sizes_not_available sna INNER JOIN Article_Size_Class asc ON sna.Size_Class=asc.Size_Class WHERE asc.Article_ID= '00024-002')
```